# SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "spool

Tags: unix, sqlplus

When i am trying to spool the result of a query, i get the below error.

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "sqool /hom..." - rest of line ignored.

sqool $FOLDER/$NAME.tmp append

select * from ABCD
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your code example and error message contain `sqool`, not the (correct) `spool` in the question title. It appears to be a simple spelling mostake in your code, and you've 'fixed' it while creating the question without noticing.

When i am trying to spool the result of a query, i get the below error. SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "sqool /hom..." - rest of line ignored.

```
spool $FOLDER/$NAME.tmp append

select * from ABCD
```

i.e. just `spool` instead of `sqool`.

Comment: thank you so much for that. I found the error as soon as i posted the question.